# r.js finishes process successfully but ignores some files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I am using requirejs in my implementation and i am using r.js for optimization. I am running following command:

```
$ "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" r.js -o name="system/enduser" out="enduser-built.js" baseUrl=. paths.jquery=em
pty: paths.cookies=empty: paths.errorhandler=empty: paths.jgrowl=empty: paths.recaptcha=empty: paths.blockui=empty:
```

That runs fine and actually produces a file which contains a lot of code from different files. But it is somehow ignoring some files for example my file looks like following:

```
paths: {
        // cdn
        jquery: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min',
        jqueryui: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min',
        recaptcha: '//www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax',

        knockout: 'knockout-latest.debug',
        underscore: 'underscore',
        blockui: 'jquery.blockui',
        jgrowl: 'jquery.jgrowl',
        infuser: 'infuser-amd',
        trafficcop: 'trafficcop-amd',
        async: 'require/async',
        depend: 'require/depend',
        font: 'require/font',
        goog: 'require/goog',
        image: 'require/image',
        json: 'require/json',
        noext: 'require/noext',
        mdown: 'require/mdown',
        propertyParser: 'require/propertyParser',
        markdownConverter: 'require/Markdown.Converter',
        passwordReset:"System/passwordreset",
        //in-house        
        cookies: 'system/cookies',
        errorhandler: 'system/errorhandler'

    },
    priority: ['jquery']
});

require(["order!jquery",
        "order!jqueryui",
        "order!knockout",
        "order!knockout.mapping-latest.debug",
        'order!system/thankyou',
        "koExternalTemplateEngine",
        "system/account",
        "system/passwordReset",
        "system/share",
        "system/utils",
        "system/tos",
        "system/surveys",
        "system/models/survey_ko",
        'system/spinzone',
        'system/facebook',
        'system/dialogs',
        'system/countdown',
        'system/registration',
        'json2',
        'system/ajax',
        'domReady!'],
      function () {
      });
```

Now, as you can see it requires Account.js from system/accounts folder but it is not loaded. It has loaded couple of files but I am not sure what is it's reason for ignoring these files. Any suggestions?